# I have an error in my sample with openiddict and docker compose

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile, openiddict

When I run openiddict in my sample: [My Docker and Openiddict Sample](https://github.com/dinhan92/DemoOpeniddictDocker), its fine, however when I run it with docker compose, I login to the server, its still fine, but when I access the Api with token, I get this error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
demomicroservice-api-1 | An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
demomicroservice-api-1 | System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain 
configuration from: 'System.String'.
demomicroservice-api-1 | ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Cannot assign requested 
address (localhost:5000)
demomicroservice-api-1 | ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested 
address
```

I thought the images is networked by the bridge, so it should connect with each other. The public api still run well. Only the private api get this error. Another scenario is that I run this openiddict with docker and run api seperately outside of the docker, it still run fine. So I have no idea here !!!